# How to use vanilla classes in react native?

Tags: javascript, class, react-native

I'm trying to call a vanilla javascript class inside a component.
This vanilla class is a distributor of cards and i wanted to separate the cards distribution logic from the component.
Where should I instanciate my vanilla class ?
How sure am I of the integrity of this instance (like when the components update) ?

I tried some things like putting in it inside useEffect(()=>{},[]) when the components mount but it didn't work (i didn't have access to my instance), I found this way but it works partially :

```
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Image,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';

import BasicMonoSlide from '../components/BasicMonoSlide';
import BasicMonoSlideDistributor from '../models/BasicMonoSlideDistributor';

export default function GameScreen(props) {

  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState({});

  const [joueurs,setJoueurs] = useState(
    JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props.joueurs))
  );
  var basicMonoSlideDistributor = new BasicMonoSlideDistributor();

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(currentSlide);
    setCurrentSlide(getBasicMonoSlide());
  },[]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(joueurs);
  },[joueurs])

  const nextSlide = () => {
    console.log("appel next slide");
    setCurrentSlide(getBasicMonoSlide());
  };

  const getBasicMonoSlide = ()=>{
    console.log("appel getBasicMonoSlide");
    var newSlideData = basicMonoSlideDistributor.getNewSlideData(joueurs,modifyJoueurs,()=>{nextSlide();});
    console.log(newSlideData[2]);
    return {type:'basicMonoSlide',slide:<BasicMonoSlide questionText={newSlideData[0]} btnText={newSlideData[1]} btnClickHandler={newSlideData[2]}/>};
  };

  const modifyJoueurs = (index,nom,sexe,orientation,enCoupleAvec,score) => {
    var joueursActuel = joueurs;
    console.log("modif du joueur a l'index "+index+" "+nom+","+sexe+","+orientation+","+enCoupleAvec+","+score);
    const newJoueursArray = joueurs.map((item, indexMap) => {
      if (indexMap === index) {
        item.index=index;
        item.nom=nom; 
        item.sexe = sexe;
        item.orientation=orientation;
        item.enCoupleAvec=enCoupleAvec;
        item.score=score;
        return item;
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    });

    setJoueurs(newJoueursArray);
}

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {currentSlide.slide||null}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

My "newSlideData[2]", the onPress given to my slide that has a button is an arrow function defined in my class BasicMonoSlideDistributor calling an arrow function defined in my component and when i click it works 1 or 2 times then does nothing

I know it's long, maybe just answer the first questions :)

Answer (score 0):

probably the slide is attached to the DOM but you don´t see this because you have problems with the CSS, check if in the element is add to the DOM (with the dev tools in your browser) and if is attached, search the problem in the CSS.